# Task scheduler +python + bat file

Tags: python, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to schedule a task in task scheduler
I have created a batch file
as below

```
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe" 
"C:\helloo\mail.py" 
 pause
```

the above is the content of my batch file.
When i run the batch file i can able to get the output . i am not facing any issue with the code which i am executing.
But with task schedular
i am following the below steps

```
1.open task schedular 
2.create task -- provided the name of the task and description 
    clicked on run whether the user is logged in or not and run with highest privileges 
3.in triggers -->new --> onetime --ok 
4.Action --> new--> action :start a program -- program script: where i kept my batch file.
5.cliked on finish 
6. i can able to find the task in task schedular but it is not showing as running
```

I need assistance in Actions tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changes in only 4 th point ,it is working as expected

```
 1.open task schedular 
 2.create task -- provided the name of the task and description 
clicked on run whether the user is logged in or not and run with highest 
 privileges 
 3.in triggers -->new --> onetime --ok 
  4.Action --> new--> program/script: where I kept my batch file.
   5.cliked on finish
```